# Anyway to make API calls to HTTP basic auth more secure?

Tags: javascript, security, api, jsonp, basic-authentication

I'm working on a few smaller projects, and probably a lot more later on, that will be using HTTP basic auth to fetch and post data. Some example APIs are [MongoHQ](http://support.mongohq.com/kb/how-tos/using-the-rest-api) and [Wufoo](http://wufoo.com/docs/api/v3/).

The projects are heavily AJAX based and for different people. For prototype purposes I have a PHP script on my server that just says the following to turn the JSON responses into JSONP:

```
<?php
  echo $_GET['callback'].'('+file_get_contents($_GET['url'])+')';
?>
```

The problem with that is my JSONP call contains the `user:pass` meaning, anyone can just view source, copy the user and pass, and then make a POST request.

Is there ways to make this secure without having to do *all* API calls directly through PHP and would allow me to use the same script from multiple projects? In the perfect world I could write a single script that would let me do HTTP basic auth stuff and never have to touch that file again no matter what API and the user and pass is somehow hidden some way (like my example above).

Answer (score 0):

You can use SSL (https) connection.

Comment: But even with SSL you can view source?

Comment: Sorry but I've probably don't understand you. But if you want to send user and password to the browser then it's impossible to secure this. On the other hand you get all data from GET so if user provided this data so why don't send him this back?

Comment: I'm providing the data in those $_GET's. I want to make sure that the basic auth's user:pass is not inside of a `$.getJSON('http://user:pass@somesite.com')`. The only way I can think of is having a "cred.php" file that has the user and pass and then my PHP script that i have above would request the user and pass from it all behind the scenes so people dont have the user and pass.